# cmake errors: Cannot find source file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake for the first time and I'm having a hard time getting this to work. There's a source file and a library file (`Lab_4.cpp` and `Trip_4.cpp`, respectively) and they're both in the source folder (`Lab_4`). Here's what's in my cmake file so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Lab_4)

#add executable
add_executable(Lab_4 ${PROJECT_SOURCE DIR}/Lab_4.cxx)
target_link_libraries (Lab_4 ${EXTRA_LISTS})

#add libraries
add_library (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Trip.cxx)
```

ls shows both files are in that folder. I'm really new to cmake so I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake but I have no idea what it is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are your libraries prebuilt? The should have `.a` or `.lib` extension if they are static libraries.

Comment: They're not. They're .cpp files that I wrote to support the main Lab_4.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

To add your sources to CMake project, you can use the [`aux_source_directory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/aux_source_directory.html) command. If your sources are in `Lab_4` folder, then you can do the following:

```
project(Lab_4)

aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Lab_4 LAB4_SOURCES)
add_executable(Lab_4 ${LAB4_SOURCES})
```

The `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is the path of the directory where the current `CMakeFiles.txt` is. The example above won't build `Trip_4.cpp` as a library but use it as another source file together with `Lab_4.cpp`.

---

If you wish to build the `Trip_4.cpp` as library fist I recommend to separate it from `Lab_4.cpp` to make later uses easier. An example directory structure could be:

```
MyProject/
|-- app/
|   |-- src/
|   |   `-- Lab_4.cpp
|   |-- inc/
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib/
|   |-- src/
|   |   `-- Trip_4.cpp
|   |-- inc/
|   `-- CMakeLists.txt
`-- CMakeLists.txt
```

In this case the `MyProject/lib/CMakeLists.txt` will contain something like the following:

```
project(Trip_4)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src TRIP4_SOURCES)

add_library(Trip_4 ${TRIP4_SOURCES})
```

The `MyProject/app/CMakeLists.txt` will be almost the same as I showed in my first example, except now it has to maintain its dependency on `Trip_4` library:

```
project(Lab_4)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src LAB4_SOURCES)

add_executable(Lab_4 ${LAB4_SOURCES})
add_dependencies(Lab_4 Trip_4)
target_link_libraries(Lab_4 Trip_4)
```

Finally, the `MyProject/CMakeLists.txt` has to tie together the library and the executable subprojects as follows:

```
project(MyProject)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your suggested folder structure, which I think I mostly understand, but I'm not sure what the `inc` folder is for? It doesn't look like there's anything in there?

Comment: @jmarck, it's a common practice to put header files into separate folders than source files. The `inc` is stands for *include* but your example doesn't contain header files so I left them empty. If you work on bigger projects and you want to keep your directory structure organized the shown structure can help. Moreover if you decide to distribute your libraries with or without your executables, the shown structure will make it easier to write install rules too.

Comment: Gotcha, that does make sense. I do have a header file for the library but I didn't think it needed to be in the cmake file.

Comment: You have to specify the include directories to let the compiler know where to search for header files you wrote after the `#include` directives.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Lab_4)

add_library(Trip_4 Lab_4/Trip4.cpp)
add_executable(Lab_4 Lab_4/Lab_4.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Lab_4 Trip_4 ${EXTRA_LISTS})
```

Your exact intentions are not completely clear, but the above are the simplest possible instructions according to your current question description.

Are you absolutely sure your CMake is version 2.6? You should update the version to whatever CMake you are currently using (type `cmake --version` to find out).

Comment: Thanks! I used 2.6 because that's what was in the example I based my file off of. The server I'm logged into has 2.8 so I'll update it.